# Salesforce Integration from Web App

Tags: apex, integration

I have a web app say 'App' , and i want to authenticate that with salesforce without connected app using the normal login page.

[image]

Can anyone say how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth is the only protocol supported by Salesforce that allows you to use the standard login page. The other methods of authentication are SOAP (which you provide your own custom UI for) and SAML (which you provide a server that users authenticate against), neither of which have the capability of using the standard login page. If you want to use the Salesforce Login page, you must use OAuth, and therefore must use a Connected App.